# Help with pico-sdk directory structure and CMake

Tags: pi-pico, cross-compilation

**Background:**
I am writing C++ code for the Pico on Windows using VS Code and CMake.

**What was working before:**
I have been writing programs successfully using the recommended directory structure:

```
+ My_Project_1
+ My_Project_2
+ pico-sdk
```

Inside each `My_Project_*` folder is a `CMakeLists.txt` file, and a copy of `pico_sdk_import.cmake`.

**What did I change:**
I changed to this structure. Just collecting my projects into their own parent folder, which itself it parallel to `pico-sdk`.

```
+ My_Projects
    + My_Project_1
    + My_Project_2
+ pico-sdk
```

**My Problem**
When I try to configure one of the projects, I get an error message from the `pico_sdk_import.cmake` file:

```
[cmake] CMake Error at pico_sdk_import.cmake:65 (message):
[cmake]   Directory 'D:/My_Projects/pico-sdk'
[cmake]   not found
```

I am not super familiar with CMake, and I can't seem to work out what I need to change to get this to work. Presumably this directory `D:/My_Projects/pico-sdk` should actually be `D:/pico-sdk`.

**Question:**
What can I change in my CMakeLists.txt file to tell CMake that my project folder is one folder deeper?

Please note that I've just simplified the directory names for this question.`pico-sdk` is not really in the root of my D: drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment variable *PICO_SDK_PATH* must be set to the location of pico-sdk (in your case to "D:/pico-sdk") before calling cmake.

You can set this variable in the "Edit environment variables for your account" window in Windows 10 (it appears in the start menu from just searching for "Path"). Once set, reopen the terminal or IDE, and recompile with cmake.